# Having an issue with bootstrap fixed-top class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The `fixed-top` class of bootstrap for the navbar is hiding a few pixels from my div. Any ideas on how to address this issue?

Please see this sample code

[Sample Code](https://codepen.io/bbeldion/pen/abvQrmv)

It seems that it is above the h1 Yehey!!!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As stated in [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/position/#fixed-top): _"Be sure you understand the ramifications of fixed position in your project; you may need to add additional CSS"_. Add some padding to the top of the div to account for the fixed navbar.

Comment: thanks bro, used `sticky-top` instead. feel free to answer the question.